# GPO Settings in CSV File via PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, active-directory

Using below PowerShell script to pull the GPO Settings Values from all GPOs in a domain but for some reasons it doesn't pull the values for all settings such SecurityOptions and UserRightsAssignment.

Have tried to modify the script but do not know which member or property to add in the loop for it to be able to collect member value.

```
# Generate GPO Report
$GPOReport = Get-GPO -All | %{
[xml](Get-GPOReport -Guid $_.Id -ReportType Xml)
}

# Blank Array to  store PSObject
$arr = @()

# Loop through each of the reports
foreach($GPOR in $GPOReport){

    # Policy Meta Data
    $PolicyName = $GPOR.GPO.Name
    $Created = $GPOR.GPO.CreatedTime -split 'T'
   $Modified = $GPOR.GPO.ModifiedTime -split 'T'

# Policy Settings
$ComputerPolicy = ($GPOR.GPO.Computer.ExtensionData.Extension)
$UserPolicy = ($GPOR.GPO.User.ExtensionData.Extension)

if($ComputerPolicy){
    
    $obj = $ComputerPolicy | Select-Xml  -XPath * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node
    switch($obj.GetType().name){
        'Object[]'{
            $obj | %{
                $PSObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject
                $PSObject | Add-Member -NotePropertyName PolicyName -NotePropertyValue $PolicyName
                $PSObject | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Created -NotePropertyValue $Created[0]
                $PSObject | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Modified -NotePropertyValue $Modified[0]

                $Name = ($_ | gm -MemberType property | select Name).Name
                $LoadObj = $_
            
                $Name | %{
                    if($_){
                        $PSObject | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $_ -NotePropertyValue $LoadObj.$_
                    }
                }
                $arr += $PSObject
            }
        }
     }
}

if($UserPolicy){
    $obj = $UserPolicy | Select-Xml  -XPath * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node
    switch($obj.GetType().name){
        'Object[]'{
            $obj | %{
                $PSObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject
                $PSObject | Add-Member -NotePropertyName PolicyName -NotePropertyValue $PolicyName
                $PSObject | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Created -NotePropertyValue $Created[0]
                $PSObject | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Modified -NotePropertyValue $Modified[0]

                $Name = ($_ | gm -MemberType property | select Name).Name
                $LoadObj = $_
            
                $Name | %{
                    if($_){
                        $PSObject | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $_ -NotePropertyValue $LoadObj.$_
                    }
                }
                $arr += $PSObject
            }
        }
     }
}
}

$arr | Select PolicyName,
  Name,
  KeyName,
  SettingNumber,     
  State,
  SettingBoolean,
  Member
  Explain,
  Created,
  Modified,
  Category,
  Supported | Export-Csv $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\GPOResults.csv    -NoTypeInformation
```

Above script returns values for registry based policy settings but not for Security Options and user rights assignment. I tried to modify the loop parameter and add Member.Name, but it doesn't do anything except it adds "System.Object[]" or "System.xml.XmlElement" in the Member column.

(CSV output):

[image: CSV Report]

Any guidance/help is much appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Isn't that the same question like the closed one before?  [GPO Settings values for all Policy Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77673491/gpo-settings-values-for-all-policy-settings)??   ... instead of creating the question ew you should update the existing one to get it reopened.  ☝

Comment: It is - I tried to update old question but to no avail. I keep seeing message about question is closed. So thought would open a new one and delete the old one. Thanks for letting me know. Deleting old question.

Comment: That sounds quite unlikely. ‍♂️

Comment: ```ConvertTo-Csv``` has some built-in ways of converting in-memory objects into strings - one of the ways it does that is to just call the ```ToString``` method on the value, which in the case of some types just returns the typename - e.g. ```System.Object[]``` or```System.Xml.XmlElement```. If you want it to return something else you'll need to decide *what* you want it to contain and pipe the objects through ```Select-Object``` first to convert the values for the appropriate properties. Alternatively, use an output format like json (e.g. ```ConvertTo-Json```) that supports complex objects.

Comment: System.Object[] is an array.   For debugging try : $GPOR.GPO.Member | Format-List  You can also use a foreach : $GPOR.GPO.Member | foreach { $_ | Format-List }

Comment: @jdweng - piping into ```Format-List``` won't solve the op's problem which is that the property value is being serialized into a csv file by calling ```ToString``` on the value - at the very least you'd need to pipe your result into ```out-string``` as well to convert the property into a string, otherwise you'll just have an array of ```FormatEntryData``` objects instead which will also serialize to ```System.Object[]``` - see for example ```@( @{ "aaa" = @("bbb", "ccc") | format-list } ) | convertto-csv``` vs ```@( @{ "aaa" = @("bbb", "ccc") | format-list | out-string } ) | convertto-csv```

Comment: @mclayton : Only said to use Format-List for debugging to find out what properties are in the object.

Comment: Thanks for those inputs. I know it's member.name.tostring() is the value that I need to fill in "Member" column. Is there any way that I can format the column name in such a way in $arr variable so script recognizes and just pulls the values?  Here: $arr | Select PolicyName,
  Name,
  KeyName,
  SettingNumber,     
  State,
  SettingBoolean,
  Member
  Explain,
  Created,
  Modified,
  Category,
  Supported | Export-Csv $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\GPOResults.csv    -NoTypeInformation

Answer (score 1):

I decided to create a new script from scratch and used all GPO Extensions manually to fetch required settings. Thanks everyone for all your help!