# script that export all the gpo settings including links to csv file

Tags: powershell, active-directory, group

if any script available that export all the gpo setting including link where gpo is applied would be great .
any script ink or tool for this ,please suggest

I tried some script but didn't work like mentioned below.
[GPO Settings in CSV File via PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77679382/gpo-settings-in-csv-file-via-powershell)
not link exported
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q06NX.png)

Comment: Asking for suggestions is off-topic. If you want to write your own script, then this is the place to ask questions about the development of that. But also not ok to ask someone to write the complete thing.